# Centos 7.2 wordpress on going to /admin shows Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wordpress/wp-admin/ on this server

Tags: htaccess, permissions

I have Centos 7.2 on our production server. When I try to go to admin on
http://patrickheide.com/wordpress/admin or
http://patrickheide.com/wordpress/wp-admin

It shows the error

> "Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /wordpress/wp-admin/ on this
>   server."

My WordPress is installed in a subdirectory and I can access admin directly like so:
http://patrickheide.com/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
there is no `/etc/httpd` directory. I don;t know how apache works, which is the problem. But anyway, I don't know what causes this problem. I tried setting everything to 777 inside wordpress subfolder and no use. `.htaccess` inside `/wordpress` subfolder is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Do you know how to find apache, or some general use global `.htaccess`. I am just throwing balls here guys, don't judge. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by simply adding this line to wordpress root .htaccess:
DirectoryIndex index.php